# API View, how filter objects by already logged user

Tags: python, django, api

I have API view which show me objects filtered by id and everything is ok but I cant change this view to filter by already logged user, model have ForeignKey related to User and I want for this View to show only objects that are related to already logged user.

This is my view for id which work:

```
class CreateComment(APIView):

def get_object(self, id):
    try:
        return Product.objects.get(id=id)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def get(self,request, id):
    product = self.get_object(id)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request, id):
    serializer = CommentSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(nick=request.user, product=self.get_object(id))
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
  def get_object(self):
    try:
        return Product.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def get(self):
    product = self.get_object()
    serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

And something like this:

```
def get(self, request):
    product = Product.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

But nothing work, 
I know about get_queryset but this is for generic Views, or maybe it is also for custom views but I don't know how use this in my view

```
#Models.py
class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True,)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('name',)
    verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('product_list', args=[self.slug])

lass Product(models.Model):
STATUS_CHOICES = (('available', 'dostępny'),
                  ('unavailable', 'niedostępny'))
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, related_name='products')
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True,)
description = models.TextField()
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', default=None)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
available = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                             default='unavailable')
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('name',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name 

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('product_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])

class Comment(models.Model):
STATUS_CHOICES = (('1/5', '1'),
                  ('2/5', '2'),
                  ('3/5', '3'),
                  ('4/5', '4'),
                  ('5/5', '5'),)
nick = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
rate = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=None)
content = models.TextField(max_length=250)
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='comments',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('published',)

def __str__(self):
    return f'Komentarz wstawiony przez {self.nick} do produktu {self.product}'
```

Comment: You should consider splitting your API endpoints up. You're using the same path but with different serializers (Product and Comment). That's generally a bad design. Does the GET path for CreateComment return a list of products or a single product?

Comment: Now it's return a single product but I want tu return list of product which are related to already logged user

Comment: Please add your models.

Comment: ok, models are added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should generate a list of products for you. The key difference is the `many=True` in `ProductSerializer`.

```
class ProductView(APIView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get(self,request, id):
        products = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thanks, its works but without id argument because with id in "get(self,request, id):" i had missing positional argument "id"

Comment: I really think you should consider redesigning your API to split the POST and GET flows to be entirely different API endpoints.

Comment: You mean that post and get should be as separately views?

Comment: Yes, because they are dealing with different types of data. The POST is creating a comment while the GET is fetching products.

Comment: thanks for advice I will use her